# Qual a diferença do service apache reload e restart?

Tags: php, apache

Qual a diferença de ambos e quais os casos pra usar algum deles?

`service apache2 restart` e `service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O `reload` diz ao serviço para recarregar seus arquivos de configuração. Isso significa que deve ser suficiente para recarregar a configuração.
>
> No entanto, pode haver certos serviços que não sigam a essa regra, ou que não recarregarão arquivos de configuração.

Retirei o trecho acima [daqui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105200/what-is-the-difference-between-service-restart-and-service-reload).

Como complemento, creio que `reload` funcione para casos tais como adição de novos sites (através do Virtualhost) ao Apache. O `reload` fará com que as configurações sejam "recarregadas", fazendo com que o novo site adicionado seja reconhecido.

Por outro lado, quando você ativa/desativa um extensão por exemplo, é
necessário reiniciar o servidor.

De maneira grosseira, resumo da seguinte forma:
O `restart` para e inicia novamente o servidor. Já o `reload` apenas recarrega as configurações. Isso soa como a diferença entre reiniciar o computador e apenas deslogar e logar novamente.

Veja que existe uma diferença entre um e outro quanto a velocidade da execução: O `reload` é sempre executado mais rápido do que `restart`, uma vez que a operação deste é mais simples.

Neste último exemplo, o `reload` é útil para evitar uma perda momentânea de conexão entre o seu servidor e o cliente que está atualmente fazendo alguma operação no seu sistema, pois a velocidade com que o `reload` é executado é quase imperceptível, ao passo que o `restart` demora um pouquinho mais.